# Using shim config with almond

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, almond

I am trying to shim certain modules for usage with almond like so:

```
<script>
requirejs.config({
  shim: {
    'jQuery': { exports: 'jQuery' },
  //etc.
</script>
```

as certain scripts will already be included. However, this code:

```
require(['jQuery', function($) {

});
```

results in "undefined missing jQuery". If I shim jQuery like this:

```
define('jQuery', function() {
  return jQuery;
});
```

it works.

I am not building my JS at all, just dropping almond.js into an existing web software so I can develop my new components with AMD. I would like to shim existing globals for my new modules.

I am guessing shims are only resolved on build and that the build does exactly what I am doing above, is that correct?

Comment: yes, Almond probably needs modules to be built into one file.

Comment: jquery is an amd module already, it doesn't need a shim config. However, it defines itself as a named module with the name `jquery`, all lower-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name for jQuery is hard-coded to "jquery". If you deviate from this you'll run into trouble. But that's not your only problem.

Using `shim` is not the same as calling `define` with a module name. When you use `shim` like you do in your question you tell the loader that there exist a module with the name `jQuery` and that *once that module is loaded*, RequireJS should return as a module value the value of the variable `jQuery`. The emphasized text is important: the loader will fetch and load a module named `jQuery`.

The `define` you show in your question would usually be placed together with the call to `require.config`, either just before it or just after it. This declares a module named `jQuery`. Because the module is already *there*, when the loader needs to get this module, there is nothing to fetch. This is an important difference when it comes to Almond.

Almond has [restrictions](https://github.com/jrburke/almond#restrictions), one of them is:

> optimize all the modules into one file -- **no dynamic code loading.**

(Emphasis added.) Using the terms I've used in this answer this means "no fetching". When you use your `define` call, you are fine. When you use the `shim`, then *unless you optimized your modules into one file*, the loader has to try fetching the module. Almond cannot do that.

Comment: Thx for your reply Louis. I understand the concepts of RequireJS and Almond. I wasn't trying to get Almond to fetch jQuery, just not to look for a module named "jQuery" and instead return the global "jQuery" object. But it looks like a) jQuery names itself "jquery" and b) the shims are resolved on-build for Almond. I ended up working with RequireJS anyway on this project. Might switch to Almond again when I build.